# Laravel 5.1 Multiple Many to Many Relationship on the Same Model

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I seen to of got tangled in Laravel's ORM with the following:

Scenerio: All Users have a Watchlist, the Watchlist contains other Users.

I can't seem the get the relationships to work correctly as they are cyclical, so far I have the following:

```
class UserWatchlist extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'UserWatchlist';

    public function Owner() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function WatchedUsers() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}


    Schema::create('UserWatchlist', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('Users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('watched_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('watched_id')->references('id')->on('Users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


class User extends Model
{


    public function Watchlist() {

        return $this->hasOne('App\UserWatchlist');
    }

    public function WatchedBy() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserWatchlist');
    }
}
```

It is not pulling through the correct in formation i'm expecting. Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `UserWatchlist` is a pivot table, i suppose you are facing a many to many relationship with both the elements of the relation being the same model (`User`)

If that is the case, you should not build a model for the pivot table `UserWatchlist` but all you have to do is to set the relation between the users through the pivot table:

```
class User extends Model
{
    //get all the Users this user is watching
    public function Watchlist() 
    {   
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'UserWatchlist', 'user_id', 'watched_id'  );
    }

    //get all the Users this user is watched by
    public function WatchedBy() 
    {    
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'UserWatchlist', 'watched_id', 'user_id' );
    }
}
```

Check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for more info on many-to-many relationship

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly. Does this also mean I don't need a Watchlist model?

Comment: exactly, you don't need the `UserWatchlist` model: you never have to write a model for a pivot table